# Mysql "where" and "and" statement from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

```
users
+---------+
|id | name|
+---------+
|1  | Tom |
|2  | Adam|
+---------+
skills
+------------+
|id  |name   |
+------------+
|1   |baking |
|2   |driving|
|3   |etc    |
+------------+

users_skills
+-----------------+
|user_id |skill_id|
+-----------------+
|  1     |    1   |
|  1     |    2   |
|  2     |    1   |
|  2     |    2   |
|  2     |    3   |
+-----------------+
```

So in result I have two users:

- Tom has 1 and 2 skill
- Adam hass 1 and 2 and 3 skill

I want to get all users that have exactly skill 1 and 2, so I want to get Tom. How to achieve that?

If I wanted to get users with skill 1 OR skill 2 - it's not a problem, but AND it is :(

Basically I tried to join users with users_skills table, but I get something like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|user_id  |name |sill_id|
+-----------------------+
|1        |Tom  |   1   |
|1        |Tom  |   2   |
+-----------------------+
etc
```

so I have two rows and I don't know how to achieve AND statement here.

Comment: You are looking for `GROUP BY users.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. The tricky part is the fact that not only has to match those skills but also NOT match any out of them.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, us.skill_id FROM users u
JOIN users_skills us ON u.id = us.user_id
WHERE u.id IN (
  SELECT user_id FROM users_skills
  WHERE user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM users_skills
    WHERE skill_id NOT IN (1, 2)
  )
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT skill_id) = 2
)
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ec639/1). Note I've also added additional users and skills to test all cases.

In short: You first get rid of the ones that have additional unwanted skills and then you get rid of the ones that have less than the needed skills.

**Output:**

```
| ID | NAME | SKILL_ID |
|----|------|----------|
|  1 |  Tom |        1 |
|  1 |  Tom |        2 |
```

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted in my question. But is it possible to change this to work with another case. I want to get all users that have specific skills, for example only the third one. I should get Adam, Carl and Mike based on your example. For 1,2 I should get Adam and Tom. Is it possible?

Comment: Just update the skills you want in the `IN` clause and change the `HAVING` clause to reflect the amount of items in the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need the DISTINCT function (and GROUP BY):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(u.name)
FROM users AS u 
JOIN users_skills AS us
ON u.id = us.user_id
WHERE us.skillID IN (1,2)
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: Not quite going to work - this will select `Adam` too, as that entity also has skills 1 and 2 (and 3, which is the problem).  Also, you don't need both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same select-clause.  Moreover, you're running into a potentially dangerous mySQL 'feature' here that can give subtly wrong results; it's safe in this instance (given the table layout), but most other RDBMSs would throw syntax errors for what you're trying to pull.